# I got this C make file error when i'm doing make

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Hello i'm working and got this C make file error when i'm doing make

> Make file:12: *** missing separator.  Stop.

thanks.

```
#
#
#
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall


all : count
.PHONY : all

count : main.o get.o
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o count main.o get.o


main.o : main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o main.o main.c

get.o : get.c
       $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o get.o get.c


debug:clean get.c main.c 
        gcc -Wall -g -o test get.c main.c
        gdb -tui test

.PHONY: clean
clean : 
        rm -rf *.o
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the output of `cat -A makefile` (assuming your `makefile` is named "makefile" of course).

Answer (score 1):

make has a very stupid relationship with tabs. All actions of every rule are identified by tabs. And, no, four spaces don't make a tab. Only a tab makes a tab.\

Just change your spaces to tabs.

On VS Code, just click the "Space: 4" on the downright corner and change it to tab when editing your Makefile.

Comment: That just means that your editor converted the TAB back to spaces when it wrote the file.  You need to find an editor that knows how to edit makefiles, which  means it knows to preserve TABs.  Alternatively you can use the `.RECIPEPREFIX` feature to change the recipe introduction character from a TAB to some other character (this requires GNU make and won't work with other versions of make).

Comment: I removed every space after the line of code, empty lines with no spaces or tabs, and changed all spaces to tabs, and it is working for me.